# Using LoadLibrary (C++) in a DLL included in Electron

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-c++, dll, electron

I have a very specific issue, where I have two DLLs which I need to include in an Electron app. In short, one controls a low-level driver in the system, and the other one is just an interface I wrote for easier access.
Basically, the interface DLL loads the driver (other DLL) dynamically with LoadLibrary in C++. I use Koffi to load the interface DLL into Electron, which works fine, however this DLL doesn't seem to be able to load the driver DLL, for whatever reason. Is it because of the electron-builder packing, that the DLL can't find another DLL that's in the same directory? If so, what can I do either on the C++ or Electron side to get this to work?

I marked the app to require admin privileges, which it does, so I'm unsure whether that's the issue for being unable to load the other DLL. The DLLs are being added to the app via the `extraResources` field in `package.json`, and I do load them properly with `process.resourcesPath`.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](/questions/107888/is-there-a-windows-msvc-equivalent-to-the-rpath-linker-flag). Very probably the search path for the nodejs executable does not encompass that where your other DLL lives.

Comment: @Botje the DLLs aren't alongside the exe, rather contained inside somehow by electron-builder. The app has to be installed first, so maybe the DLLs are in the install folder, in which case they'd have no problem finding each other.

Comment: @Botje yeah, I can confirm the DLLs are alongside each other in the install folder, something like `AppData/Local/Programs/my-app/resources/resources`. In all other testing when I placed them one alongside each other it simply worked, and it found the other DLL no problem.